# Find column number in excel sheet using openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying to get the column number in a excel sheet if the cell value matches string value. Script should look for the string in the excel sheet and if match is found, corresponding column number should be returned. For example, I want to find column number corresponding to cell with value = "ABC".
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRian.png)

What I have tried so far:
I am able to find match in a particular column but I don't want to hardcore column number as the excel is updated regularly.

```
wb = load_workbook(filename)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name) 
search_string = "ABC"


def search_value_in_column(ws, search_string):
    for row, col in range(1, ws.max_row + 1, ws.max_col +1):
        if ws[row][col].value == search_string:
            return col, row
    return col, None
```

I am new to openpyxl, please let me know how we can solve this.

Comment: @Tomerikoo Not completely, Script should return the column number or index if match is found..

Comment: Well the link above shows you how to find the cell. Then you can just do `cell.column` to get its column...

Comment: @Tomerikoo yup I got what I was looking for.. Thank you for the solution.